# Decimal binary sequences that cannot be greater than 1

Tags: nt.number-theory

Consider the family of sequences of the form $.012\ldots n$ for any natural number $n$. So, the sequences in this family are: $.01, .012, .0123, .01234,$ etc.

Now consider to manipulate each sequence in this way:

1) Start from the rightmost digit; let's say that the rightmost digit is $n$;
2) If $n$ is even, replace $n$ by $0$ and add $n/2$ to the digit immediately on the left;
3) if $n$ is odd, replace $n$ by $1$ and add $(n-1)/2$ to the digit immediately on the left;
4) keep on modifying the sequence on the left until the only digits are '$0$' and '$1$'.

E.g., suppose that you consider the sequence $.01234.$ Then you modify it in this way: $.01250; .01410; .03010; .11010$.

I want to show that, for any $n$, after rewriting the sequence with only '$0$' and '$1$', I will never obtain any sequence that starts in this way $x.yy$'$y$'... where $x\neq 0$. So, e.g., I will never obtain any sequence like $1.0101$.

This problem is probably analogous to show that any sequence of the form $(0*2^{-1})+(1*2^{-2})+(2*2^{-3})+...+(n*2^{-(n+1)})$ is $<1$. However, I am not sure how to prove it.

Comment: What do you do when digits go over 10?

Comment: I will give an example: .0123456789; .01234567(12)1; .0123456(13)01; .012345(12)101; .01234(11)0101; .01234910101; etc. So we can imagine that sequences are actually of this form .(x)(y)(z)... The use of parenthesis is unnecessary when numbers are of one digit only. Thanks for asking.

Comment: Previously asked at http://math.stackexchange.com/q/950940/18398

Comment: It is true. I am sorry. I did not know this is annoying to someone. I understand it now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The decimal representation is a red herring. You have an operation that acts on sequences $(a_0,a_1,a_2,\dots)$ by modifying adjacent entries
$$a'_n=a_n \pmod{2}$$ 
$$a'_{n-1}=a_{n-1}+\lfloor n/2 \rfloor$$
The quantity $\sum \frac{a_n}{2^n}$ is left invariant at every step and is easily seen to be less than $2$ for any of your finite sequences. This implies the desired conclusion.